# Selenium Tests fail for different reasons in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fix a number of unit tests which use Selenium Edge Web Driver for C#.

Sometimes the tests run through once without falling, but if you run them again they fail. However, the failures are not consistent and the reasons are numerous. For example, it could time out, or cannot find an element or a title of a document on the page.

I have tried all sorts of things such using wait load until, but this is unreliable if the elements cannot be found.

Has anyone else experienced this and how was it solved?

Comment: I think you're going to have to take this one reason at a time.  We need to be able to repeat the behavior or see the code and/or markup for each.  Include full exceptions thrown.  (So I'd break this up into 1 question per fail as they're likely to close it for being too broad...)

Answer (score 0):

This situation is called **`Fleaky`** tests. There could be several reasons:

- Network latency(timeouts)
- data related issues
- Not stabil waitings
- Dynamic HTML content that in your code doesnt have flexible selectors.

So, without actual code it is not possible to make any comment

Comment: The tests are against SharePoint 2013 which displays data dynamically based upon user action. We are using xpath to find the elements. Would using element IDs be better or something else?